# Spring Boot - how to handle UnrecognizedPropertyException from Jackson manually?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot, jackson

So I have a controller that takes input a request body:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo/bar")
public class FooBarController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> doTheFoo(@RequestBody MyDto dto) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I have this FooBar:

```
public clas FooBar {
    @JsonProperty("foo")
    private String foo;

    public void setFoo(String foo) { ... }
    public String getFoo() { ... }
}
```

And I have set in my properties to fail on unknown properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties: true
```

And I also have a handler to try and capture the failure:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleUnrecognizedPropertyException(UnrecognizedPropertyException ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I POST to my endpoint with an unknown property (e.g. `{"bar": "baz"}`), nothing in the GlobalExceptionHandler is run and instead a vanilla 400 BAD REQUEST is returned. How do I intercept the unknown property exception and provide a different response?

Comment: If no unknown property being post, is the controller works correctly?

Comment: That's not the point; I want to return a custom error page and not an empty page with a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: I was asking because 4xx is client error requests. Was it because your post being sent as form while the controller ask for json? Or maybe other reason, that made your exception handler doesn't caught the specified exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using properly the property and your controller works well, you could intercept the HttpMessageNotReadableException exception.

Comment: The additional problem I had was that I couldn't override the extended ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class (wasn't originally in post). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try BasicErrorController of Spring Boot. This should look something like this.

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping
   public class ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping( value = "/error/404.html" )
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String pageNotFoundError( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        "errors/404"
    }
```